# TYPO3 RTE remove <p class="bodytext"></p> in nested ul

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

In my TYPO3 6.2.31 instance in nested `<ul>` RTE adds `<p class="bodytext"></p>`.

In backend the code looks like this:

```
<ul>
 <li> Text
   <ul>
     <li> Text
```

In frontend when its rendered the code looks like this:

```
<ul>
 <li> Text
   <p class="bodytext"></p>
   <ul>
     <li> Text
```

How can I prevent TYPO3 and RTE to add this `<p class="bodytext"></p>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this TypoScript:

```
lib.parseFunc_RTE.nonTypoTagStdWrap.encapsLines.nonWrappedTag >
```